# Error after upgrade to angular 6: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'

Tags: angular

Just update angular from 5.2 to 6.0.3 following https://update.angular.io/
but I have this error if I try to serve the application.
`ng update` says it is all updated.

Anyone know ho to solve it?
Or why it happens

> ERROR in
>   ../node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11):
>   error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
>   node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error
>   TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.

this is my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0.4",
  "license": "",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "dev": "lite-server",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "animate.css": "3.5.2",
    "arrive": "2.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "4.1.1",
    "bootstrap-notify": "3.1.3",
    "bootstrap-rtl": "3.3.4",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "0.7.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "googleapis": "22.2.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "intl-tel-input": "^12.1.15",
    "jasny-bootstrap": "^3.1.3",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.13",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-trim-directive": "^2.1.4",
    "ngx-chips": "^1.9.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.6.1",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.1.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "primeng": "^6.0.0-alpha.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.21.1",
    "uglify-js": "1.3.5",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^4.0.0",
    "validate": "3.0.1",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/bootstrap": "3.3.36",
    "@types/chartist": "0.9.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.6.0",
    "@types/jquery": "3.2.13",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.17",
    "angular-ide": "^0.9.41",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "protractor": "^5.3.2",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24165

Comment: Yes I am always me, no one solve this question